# scaling a text within a rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling

I draw a rectangle r which is 4 time the size of some word w;
I would like the word w to be 3 time its initial size (and drawn in r).
I don't know how to get my multiplication factor, 3 in this example,
i.e. I dont know how to modify "{\textbf{abc}}" in the line starting width \draw.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\newlength{\la}
\newlength{\ha}
\setlength{\la}{\widthof{\textbf{abc}}*\real{4.0}}
\setlength{\ha}{\totalheightof{\textbf{abc}}*\real{4.0}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (\la,\ha) node[pos=.5] {\textbf{abc}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\la}{4*width("\textbf{abc}")}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ha}{4*height("\textbf{abc}")}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle  node[font=\bfseries,scale=3] {abc} 
(\la pt,\ha pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: when I compile this code I get an error: \inaccessible l.4 \pgfmathsetmacro ... (I am currently using the 2017 texlive distribution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\scalebox{3}{\textbf{abc}}`, as in

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\newlength{\la}
\newlength{\ha}
\setlength{\la}{\widthof{\textbf{abc}}*\real{4.0}}
\setlength{\ha}{\totalheightof{\textbf{abc}}*\real{4.0}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (\la,\ha) node[pos=.5] {\scalebox{3}{\textbf{abc}}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To get the same vertical, horizontal extra margins, I use the same multiplication factor in the \setlength and \draw commands, and add some increment in the \setlength commands (otherwise the horizontal margin is too big wrt the vertical margin, specially for longer words)

Comment: @NicolasBeldiceanu Depending on your application, a simple `\fbox{\scalebox{3}{...}}` could suffice (without `tikz`), with `\fboxsep` set to an appropriate value. In such a case, the surrounding margin is uniform, rather than scaled.

Comment: One thing I did not mention, is that I want to get the exact size of the rectangle (i.e. to get the values of \la and \ha) and give these size to some external program, which compute the positions of a set of rectangles of a word cloud, so that I can generate a tikz word cloud (with hyperref links). So I need to feed my word cloud generator with the appropriate rectangle sizes, then my generator will generate the tikz code of the resulting word cloud.

Answer (score 1):

I did not plan on posting this but you seem to get an error. This is the code from my above comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\la}{4*width("\textbf{abc}")}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ha}{4*height("\textbf{abc}")}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle  node[font=\bfseries,scale=3] {abc} 
(\la pt,\ha pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is arguably more Ti*k*Zy, it used the pgf functions `width` and `height` to compute the width and height of the text, and `scale` to scale the text.